# Do I need my UK Visitor Visa first if my first place of arrival is UK before applying for Schengen Visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

So we'll be taking a flight from India to UK and then we'll be taking a train to Paris. But since UK has a rule where you can only apply 3 months prior for Visa, we wanted to apply for Schengen first. So can we apply for Schengen without holding the UK Visitor Visa? Confused because our train would be from UK to France.

Comment: For your Schengen visa it does not matter how and from where you arrive, for your UK visa it is important that you can leave the way you plan.